# Conversion of datetime format

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have column name **requestdatetime** with data type string.
Value for **requestdatetime** is in format **15/Aug/2022:01:54:41 +0000**

I need to convert **15/Aug/2022:01:54:41 +0000** into '`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` format.

I have tried `date_parse(requestdatetime,'%d/%b/%Y'':''HH:mm:ss'' ''+SSS')` but it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_parse` accepts MySQL date format, try `parse_datetime` which accepts [Java format](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions) (do not forget to add part for timezone offset - `Z`):

```sql
SELECT parse_datetime('15/Aug/2022:01:54:41 +0000', 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-15 01:54:41.000 UTC |

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to date then date to string to get expected result.

```
select date_format(parse_datetime('15/Aug/2022:01:54:41 +0000','dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z'), '%Y/%m/%d %T')
```

result:

```
2022/08/15 01:54:41
```